# How to add thing to the tool bar application launcher

Tags: raspbian, lxde

I want to add things to the toolbar via the terminal not gui i have already put the file in the polecat ion menu is start menu

Comment: *Presumably* you are referring to LXDE, the default desktop environment on Raspbian.  If so, you should ask about it on the Unix & Linux Exchange, and specify that it is with regard to LXDE -- there's [a tag](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lxde).  If not, do the same thing specifying whatever DE it is you are using.  The fact that it's on a pi doesn't matter.  The specific distribution (in this case raspbian) probably doesn't matter much either for GUI/DE oriented questions, but it doesn't hurt to mention it.

Comment: I don't want to join any more stacks so I would just like an answer here

Comment: Okay -- I'll reopen this mostly to demonstrate a point to you.  I'm dubious that anyone anywhere has an answer to this, not because it is a bad question but because it is pretty obscure (and may not have an answer at all).  Your best chance, though, will be either on U&L or [LXDE's own forum](http://forum.lxde.org/).  I think here you will get mostly crickets ;)  That's why stuff gets migrated.   It's not to be a stickler, etc.